# How do I invert a matrix in F#?

Tags: f#, matrix

I need to perform some basic OLS regression using F#. To do this I need some Linear Algebra functions, but I'm confused as to what's out there. I can't find any way to invert a matrix. There is some documentation for a library called `Microsoft.FSharp.Math.LinearAlgebra`, but I don't know if that exists anymore.

Comment: Depends what your element type is. `Microsoft.FSharp.Math.Experimental.LinearAlgebra.Inverse` only supports `float`, IIRC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you add the FSharp Powerpack to your project (in .NET references), you can use various functionality of the matrix library

edit: you also need to add the experimental library Fsharp.Powerpack.MathProviders, then you can call as follows

```
open    Microsoft.FSharp.Math
let m = Matrix.create 10 10 1.2
let m2 = Experimental.LinearAlgebra.Inverse m
```

Comment: I can create a Matrix just fine, I can add them, multiply them and even transpose them, but I can't invert them.

Comment: The code I had to use was
Microsoft.FSharp.Math.Experimental.LinearAlgebra.Inverse(m)

But that works, thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

[FlyingFrog](http://www.ffconsultancy.com/) do a [Numerics](http://www.ffconsultancy.com/products/fsharp_for_numerics/index.html) library which contains Matrix inversion amongst many other functions.

Not sure which is preferable, that or the (apparently deprecated) 'experimental' code from the PowerPack. I guess you could always keep the source code for the managed bit of the PowerPack version in a safe place, still available here:

```
C:\Program Files\FSharp-1.9.6.2\source\fsharp\FSharp.PowerPack\math\lapack\linear_algebra_managed.fs.
```

Comment: If you're inverting huge floating point matrices then the experimental code from the old F# Power Pack will give better performance (if you can get it to work!). If you're doing small matrices or other types (e.g. exact inversion via arbitrary-precision rational arithmetic) then F# for Numerics is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know; in the 1.9.6 version of F# I don't see anything offhand, the docs are here

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/namespaces.html

and there is Matrix stuff in the Microsoft.FSharp.Math namespace in the FSharp.Powerpack.dll, but I don't see 'invert' offhand, and I don't know about the 'LinearAlgebra' stuff (deprecated? web search suggests it disappeared a few releases back).

Comment: Goodness, if you don't know, what hope is there for the rest of us? :) The dll is in 1.9.6.2 CTP and nothing indicates that it is deprecated (except it's absence from the docs, I guess...)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out [this](http://cs.hubfs.net/forums/thread/258.aspx).  It might help.

Comment: Does dnAnalytics still exist? I can't get to their webpage anymore.

Comment: That would be a shame.  I didn't try digging around for it and I appologize if this is a dead end. :(

Comment: It appears that codeplex was down for maintenance. dnAnalytics seems to be back today.

Comment: dnAnalytics is being merged with Math.NET Iridium to make Math.NET Numerics: http://www.mathdotnet.com/